# media query issues switching between two nav menus

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu that consists of two separate menus that are triggered by media queries.

codepen is:http://codepen.io/iamgonge/pen/QpOgZB (design suggestions appreciated)

css:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px;) { #big{display:none;}}
     @media only screen and (min-width: 769px;) { #little {display: none;}}
```

at 767px the mobile hamburger menu is visible at 768px it's the mobile nav but not collapsible, at 769px its the desktop nav. I'd like the mobile nav to show the collapsible menu up to and including 768(Ipad portrait)what is making the menu at 768px appear the way it does?

Answer (score 0):

You have to customized the css for the width of 768px:

Navabar with class .in display in table
nav ul li{display:block; float:left; width:100%;}
.collapse.in{overflow-y:visible;}

In short you have to customize the css if you want to show the mobile nav as toggle menu on 768px.